# Escape a table name in sql alchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to **escape table names** for any sqlalchemy engine (I want to expand a library I made for other databases than postgres, see Details section at the end of my post) **automatically**.

It is possible with columns like this:

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import column
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///test.db")
escaped_column = column('%"my_column123?').compile(dialect=engine.dialect)
str(escaped_column)
```

```py
'"%""my_column123?"'
```

I (naively) tried the following but it does not work (gives back an empty string):

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import table
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///test.db")
escaped_table_name = table("%table?&;").compile(dialect=engine.dialect)
str(escaped_table_name)
```

```py
''
```

Thanks in advance!

### Details

I made a library to update PostGres table using pandas DataFrames (see https://github.com/ThibTrip/pangres) and realized that a part of the code is not SQL injection safe (if you are curious here is the part I am talking about: https://github.com/ThibTrip/pangres/blob/7cfa2d2190cf65a1ede8ef30868883f0da3fa5fc/pangres/helpers.py#L270-L290).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to add columns in a "sqlalchemy way" (adding columns to any table was the reason why I wanted to escaped table names). Unfortunately it is not perfect as it creates a table "alembic_version" for some reasons:

```py
# alembic is a library from the creator of sqlalchemy to migrate databases
from alembic.runtime.migration import MigrationContext # pip install alembic
from alembic.operations import Operations
from sqlalchemy import Column, TEXT, create_engine # pip install sqlalchemy

# create engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')

# add column "some_new_column" of type TEXT in the table 'test'
with engine.connect() as con:
    ctx = MigrationContext.configure(con, )
    op = Operations(ctx)
    op.add_column('test', column=Column('some_new_column', TEXT))
```

EDIT: it seems the table "alembic_version" has been added somehow by previous tests as I could not reproduce this behavior after dropping the table. So this solution seems good :)!!!